# How do I make a route as default when multiple routes are defined?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have an mvc Website in which there was a default route specified.

I have a url in my application which defines as :

http://localhost:3729/Information?Cust_ID=1&Cust_IMAGE_ID=2

I do not my Url to be appeared as above but in the format as above but like the below one:

http://localhost:3729/Information/1/2

So I have defined a route like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Information",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{Cust_ID}/{Cust_IMAGE_ID}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Information", action = "Index", Cust_ID = UrlParameter.Optional, Cust_IMAGE_ID = UrlParameter.Optional
});
```

and added this to the existing routeconfig.cs.

This route stood second in the route table.

When I run the application and visit the page, I am not getting the format I wish.

When I place this route in the first, I get the functionality I desired but the application is directly opening this page but not the home page.

How to implement the functionality I desire.

My question is - Of the multiple routes defined in the route table, I want to make one route as default.

Comment: What is the other route? And remove `Cust_ID = UrlParameter.Optional` (only the last route can be optional, and if the other route is `url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}` then remove `Cust_IMAGE_ID = UrlParameter.Optional` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 main issues:

1. Specific routes must be declared before general routes.
2. The URL pattern you have defined does not match the intended URL `http://localhost:3729/Information/1/2`.

To solve them, you should define the route *before* the default route as follows.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Information",
    url: "Information/{Cust_ID}/{Cust_IMAGE_ID}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Information", action = "Index", Cust_IMAGE_ID = UrlParameter.Optional
});

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

You also have defined your "information" URL with an optional `Cust_ID` parameter, which I am guessing does not make any sense (unless you want the URL `/Information` to list all customers). It may also not make any sense to make `Cust_IMAGE_ID` optional depending on your requirements.

> On a side note, putting the customer image ID into the URL seems like a bad idea if the image is actually displayed on the page. This means that a user could alter the URL to pull up an image of a different customer that is unrelated to the current customer.